# Custom implementation of doubly linked list not working (educational)

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I implemented my own simple version of a doubly linked list. Unfortunately, there seems to be an error with it. The head of the list seems to move to the new `Node`, each time I add one with `push_back`. Because of this, `print` will print the last value indefinitely.

**Linked List:**

```
struct doubly_linked_list
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;
    void push_back(Node n)
    {
        if (this->head == nullptr)
        {
            this->head = &n;
            this->tail = nullptr;
        }
        n.prev = this->tail;
        if (this->tail)
        {
            n.prev->next = &n;
        }
        this->tail = &n;
    }
    void print()
    {
        Node *tmp = this->head;
        while (tmp != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << tmp->data << ", ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
};
```

Where **Node** is implemented as

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
    Node()
    {
        this->data = -1;
    }
};
```

**main**

```
int main()
{
    doubly_linked_list dl;
    dl.push_back(Node{3});
    dl.push_back(Node{2});
    dl.push_back(Node{1});
    dl.push_back(Node{0});
    dl.push_back(Node{5});
    dl.print(); // print 5 forever
}
```

Disclaimer: Pls be aware that the topic of this post is educational. I know about the lists in the c++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with raw pointers, deppending on what you are doing you might want to change that to smart pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
    Node()
    {
        this->data = -1;
    }
};

struct doubly_linked_list
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;
    void push_back(Node* n)
    {
        if (this->head == nullptr)
        {
            this->head = n;
            this->tail = nullptr;
        }
        n->prev = this->tail;
        if (this->tail)
        {
            n->prev->next = n;
        }
        this->tail = n;
    }
    void print()
    {
        Node *tmp = this->head;
        while (tmp != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << tmp->data << ", ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
     }
};

int main()
{
    doubly_linked_list dl;
    dl.push_back(new Node{3});
    dl.push_back(new Node{2});
    dl.push_back(new Node{1});
    dl.push_back(new Node{0});
    dl.push_back(new Node{5});
    dl.print(); // print 5 forever
}
```